# Pretrained model to classify text as address or not

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, text-classification

I am training a text classifier for addresses such that if given sentence is an address or not.

```
Sentence examples :- 
(1) Mirdiff City Centre, DUBAI United Arab Emirates 
(2) Ultron Inc. <numb> Toledo Beach Rd #1189 La Salle, MI <numb>
(3) Avenger - HEAD OFFICE P.O. Box <numb> India
```

As addresses can be of n types it's very difficult to make such classifier. Is there any pre-trained model or database for the same or any other non ML way.